# how to pass link parameter when i click the export excel button?

Tags: php, laravel

I need help to pass the parameter on URL.

### routes.php

```
Route::get('downloadExcel/{type}', 'ExcelController@downloadExcel');
```

### blade.php

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/downloadExcel/xls') }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm hidden-print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i> Export to Excel</a>
```

### controller

```
class ExcelController extends Controller{
    public function downloadExcel($type, Request $request)
    {
     return Excel::create('Laporan Kehadiran Harian', function($excel) use 
      ($transaksi) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($transaksi)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($transaksi);
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you declare the type as variable?

Comment: @kusy yes..please refer on my controller :) i want change url on href.

Comment: what is issue from your code ? it should work

Comment: @Hemelraj i want to pass the url when i click export to excel sir. href="{{ URL::to('/downloadExcel/xls') }}"

Comment: could you paste controller where you call that view?

Comment: the code to long sir..i code all in controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the blade.php try to set a second parameter as an array with the `type` property and the value you want to pass.

If it is "xls" it would be the following:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/downloadExcel', array("type" => "xls")) }}"></a>
```

Comment: That't true. But the question was about the parameter in the link.

The data is missing because your $transaksi variable has no value. Assign data to that before the return statement.

Comment: data already exist sir..all i need is to pass the link on URL. like above

Comment: ok sir i have the solution now. <a href="{{ route('downloadExcel', ['export' => 'excel'] + request()->query()) }}"